# Run a check for multiple meta key values

Tags: custom-field, array, post-meta, meta-value

I am having a heck of a time getting wordpress to display all values of a certain meta key correctly. I wonder if I am going about this the wrong way?

My end goal is to run a check to see if there is more than one custom field value in a key. If there is, each value should be listed with a comma delimiter, but no comma on the last value. If there is not, no comma should be used. I have tried two methods unsuccessfully. The first is get_post_meta:

```
<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'band', true)): ?>
    <strong>Band:</strong> <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'band'); ?><br />
<?php endif; ?>
```

According to the codex, this should display all values of that key, but instead all it does is echo "array". If I change $Single to true, like so:

```
<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'band', true)): ?>
    <strong>Band:</strong> <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'band', true); ?><br />
<?php endif; ?>
```

it only returns the first value (but at least returns the value and not the word "array".

The second method I have tried that sorta worked was get_post_custom_values. This does the trick, but I can't work out how to a) run a check for multiple values or b) keep it from adding a comma to the last value.

```
<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'gear', true)): ?>
    <strong>Gear: </strong>
    <?php
      $mykey_values = get_post_custom_values('gear');
      foreach ( $mykey_values as $key => $value ) {
        echo "$value, "; 
      }
    ?>  
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use php's [`implode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to join array elements with a string:

```
<?php
if( $bands = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'band') ):
    ?>
    <strong>Band:</strong> <?php echo implode( $bands, ', ' ); ?><br />
    <?php
endif;
?>
```

EDIT- another version of above, pluralizing the label depending on single or multiple meta values:

```
<?php
if( $bands = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'band') ):
    $label = count( $bands ) > 1 ? 'Bands' : 'Band';
    ?>
    <strong><?php echo $label; ?>:</strong> <?php echo implode( $bands, ', ' ); ?><br />
    <?php
endif;
?>
```